# When configuring SMTP parameters, mail is not sent

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp, phpmailer, mailer

I have a problem which, as I mention in the title, after configuring the SMTP parameters in wp-config and functions.php the email is not sent. If I don't configure this data, the email will be sent as SPAM (PHP's default mailer service).

This is my SMTP configuration at wp-config.php:

```
define( 'SMTP_USER',   'edouard.duval@brief.fr' );    // Username to use for SMTP authentication
define( 'SMTP_PASS',   'CHANGEDFORTHEPOSTSECURITY' );       // Password to use for SMTP authentication
define( 'SMTP_HOST',   'smtp.brief.fr' );    // The hostname of the mail server
define( 'SMTP_PORT',   '587' );                  // SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
define( 'SMTP_SECURE', 'ssl' );                 // Encryption system to use - ssl or tls
define( 'SMTP_AUTH',    true );                // Use SMTP authentication (true|false)
define( 'SMTP_DEBUG',   1 );                    // for debugging purposes only set to 1 or 2
```

And this is my configuration in functions.php (declared at the beginning of the file):

```
// Send email via SMTP
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer' );
function my_phpmailer( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();     
    $phpmailer->Host = SMTP_HOST;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = SMTP_AUTH;
    $phpmailer->Port = SMTP_PORT;
    $phpmailer->Username = SMTP_USER;
    $phpmailer->Password = SMTP_PASS;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SECURE;
}
```

Apparently when calling the ajax function that sends the mail, wp_mail () returns success (true) but I don't see the mail arrive.

If anyone knows that it may be failing please help, thank you very much and regards.

Comment: just want to double check : is your server using  'ssl' and not 'tls' in 'SMTP_SECURE'?

Comment: From what I understand from my host, either option works. I tried adding ssl: // to the beginning of the host but nothing ..

https://prnt.sc/15m4z04

Answer (score 1):

`SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` will not work on port 587. Either change port to 465, or change the TLS mode to `'tls'` *but not both!* This is what all the PHPMailer examples and [docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#encryption-flavours) say to do, so I don't know why you chose those values.

Comment: tried to use Easy WP SMTP with the same parameters but when testing an email it returns the following error:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/417852821791178754/854748648126545950/unknown.png?width=960&height=415

Here the config of the plugin:

Comment: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/417852821791178754/854748930516713522/unknown.png?width=960&height=440

Comment: In that last screen shot you have the same incorrect configuration. Use STARTTLS with port 587, SMTPS with port 465. You should change your password since you just posted an image of it in public.

Comment: What happened when you tried the tests in the troubleshooting guide?